# Wampserver not working on HTTPS with Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, https, wamp

I tried to make HTTPS work on my local Symfony2 application.

Without HTTPS enabled i got this :

My normal config :

```
 access_control:
        # URL of FOSUserBundle which need to be available to anonymous users
        - { path: ^/_wdt, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/_profiler, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # Secured part of the site
        # This config requires being logged for the whole site and having the admin role for the admin part.
        # Change these rules to adapt them to your needs
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }


        - { path: ^/user/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        - { path: ^/user$, role: ROLE_USER }

        - { path: ^/acv$, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/urba$, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/design$, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/distrib$, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/flux$, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/product$, role: ROLE_USER }


        - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY ,requires_channel: http}
```

[The normal page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwkY9.jpg)

And when i enable HTTPS, i got this :

Config HTTPS :

```
 access_control:
        # URL of FOSUserBundle which need to be available to anonymous users
        - { path: ^/_wdt, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/_profiler, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # Secured part of the site
        # This config requires being logged for the whole site and having the admin role for the admin part.
        # Change these rules to adapt them to your needs
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }


        - { path: ^/user/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/logout$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        - { path: ^/user$, role: ROLE_USER }

        - { path: ^/acv$, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/urba$, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/design$, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/distrib$, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/flux$, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/product$, role: ROLE_USER }


        - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY ,requires_channel: https}
```

[Page not working with HTTPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xz91B.png)

Here's my Virtualhost :

```
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName artogreen
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/artogreen/web"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/artogreen/web">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My SSL virtual host :

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/"
ServerName localhost:443
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ErrorLog "c:/wamp64/bin/apache/Apache2.4.51/logs/ssl_error.log"
TransferLog "c:/wamp64/bin/apache/Apache2.4.51/logs/ssl_access.log"

#   SSL Engine Switch:
#   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
SSLEngine on

#   Server Certificate:
#   Point SSLCertificateFile at a PEM encoded certificate.  If
#   the certificate is encrypted, then you will be prompted for a
#   pass phrase.  Note that a kill -HUP will prompt again.  Keep
#   in mind that if you have both an RSA and a DSA certificate you
#   can configure both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA
#   ciphers, etc.)
#   Some ECC cipher suites (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4492.txt)
#   require an ECC certificate which can also be configured in
#   parallel.
SSLCertificateFile "c:/wamp64/bin/apache/Apache2.4.51/conf/cert/certificat.crt"
#SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server-dsa.crt"
#SSLCertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server-ecc.crt"

#   Server Private Key:
#   If the key is not combined with the certificate, use this
#   directive to point at the key file.  Keep in mind that if
#   you've both a RSA and a DSA private key you can configure
#   both in parallel (to also allow the use of DSA ciphers, etc.)
#   ECC keys, when in use, can also be configured in parallel
SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/wamp64/bin/apache/Apache2.4.51/conf/key/private.key"
#SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server-dsa.key"
#SSLCertificateKeyFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server-ecc.key"

#   Server Certificate Chain:
#   Point SSLCertificateChainFile at a file containing the
#   concatenation of PEM encoded CA certificates which form the
#   certificate chain for the server certificate. Alternatively
#   the referenced file can be the same as SSLCertificateFile
#   when the CA certificates are directly appended to the server
#   certificate for convenience.
#SSLCertificateChainFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/server-ca.crt"

#   Certificate Authority (CA):
#   Set the CA certificate verification path where to find CA
#   certificates for client authentication or alternatively one
#   huge file containing all of them (file must be PEM encoded)
#   Note: Inside SSLCACertificatePath you need hash symlinks
#         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
#         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
#SSLCACertificatePath "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl.crt"
#SSLCACertificateFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt"

#   Certificate Revocation Lists (CRL):
#   Set the CA revocation path where to find CA CRLs for client
#   authentication or alternatively one huge file containing all
#   of them (file must be PEM encoded).
#   The CRL checking mode needs to be configured explicitly
#   through SSLCARevocationCheck (defaults to "none" otherwise).
#   Note: Inside SSLCARevocationPath you need hash symlinks
#         to point to the certificate files. Use the provided
#         Makefile to update the hash symlinks after changes.
#SSLCARevocationPath "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl.crl"
#SSLCARevocationFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/ssl.crl/ca-bundle.crl"
#SSLCARevocationCheck chain

#   Client Authentication (Type):
#   Client certificate verification type and depth.  Types are
#   none, optional, require and optional_no_ca.  Depth is a
#   number which specifies how deeply to verify the certificate
#   issuer chain before deciding the certificate is not valid.
#SSLVerifyClient require
#SSLVerifyDepth  10

#   TLS-SRP mutual authentication:
#   Enable TLS-SRP and set the path to the OpenSSL SRP verifier
#   file (containing login information for SRP user accounts). 
#   Requires OpenSSL 1.0.1 or newer. See the mod_ssl FAQ for
#   detailed instructions on creating this file. Example:
#   "openssl srp -srpvfile ${SRVROOT}/conf/passwd.srpv -add username"
#SSLSRPVerifierFile "${SRVROOT}/conf/passwd.srpv"

#   Access Control:
#   With SSLRequire you can do per-directory access control based
#   on arbitrary complex boolean expressions containing server
#   variable checks and other lookup directives.  The syntax is a
#   mixture between C and Perl.  See the mod_ssl documentation
#   for more details.
#<Location />
#SSLRequire (    %{SSL_CIPHER} !~ m/^(EXP|NULL)/ \
#            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_O} eq "Snake Oil, Ltd." \
#            and %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} in {"Staff", "CA", "Dev"} \
#            and %{TIME_WDAY} >= 1 and %{TIME_WDAY} <= 5 \
#            and %{TIME_HOUR} >= 8 and %{TIME_HOUR} <= 20       ) \
#           or %{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ m/^192\.76\.162\.[0-9]+$/
#</Location>

#   SSL Engine Options:
#   Set various options for the SSL engine.
#   o FakeBasicAuth:
#     Translate the client X.509 into a Basic Authorisation.  This means that
#     the standard Auth/DBMAuth methods can be used for access control.  The
#     user name is the `one line' version of the client's X.509 certificate.
#     Note that no password is obtained from the user. Every entry in the user
#     file needs this password: `xxj31ZMTZzkVA'.
#   o ExportCertData:
#     This exports two additional environment variables: SSL_CLIENT_CERT and
#     SSL_SERVER_CERT. These contain the PEM-encoded certificates of the
#     server (always existing) and the client (only existing when client
#     authentication is used). This can be used to import the certificates
#     into CGI scripts.
#   o StdEnvVars:
#     This exports the standard SSL/TLS related `SSL_*' environment variables.
#     Per default this exportation is switched off for performance reasons,
#     because the extraction step is an expensive operation and is usually
#     useless for serving static content. So one usually enables the
#     exportation for CGI and SSI requests only.
#   o StrictRequire:
#     This denies access when "SSLRequireSSL" or "SSLRequire" applied even
#     under a "Satisfy any" situation, i.e. when it applies access is denied
#     and no other module can change it.
#   o OptRenegotiate:
#     This enables optimized SSL connection renegotiation handling when SSL
#     directives are used in per-directory context. 
#SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>

<Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/artogreen/">
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#   SSL Protocol Adjustments:
#   The safe and default but still SSL/TLS standard compliant shutdown
#   approach is that mod_ssl sends the close notify alert but doesn't wait for
#   the close notify alert from client. When you need a different shutdown
#   approach you can use one of the following variables:
#   o ssl-unclean-shutdown:
#     This forces an unclean shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. no
#     SSL close notify alert is sent or allowed to be received.  This violates
#     the SSL/TLS standard but is needed for some brain-dead browsers. Use
#     this when you receive I/O errors because of the standard approach where
#     mod_ssl sends the close notify alert.
#   o ssl-accurate-shutdown:
#     This forces an accurate shutdown when the connection is closed, i.e. a
#     SSL close notify alert is send and mod_ssl waits for the close notify
#     alert of the client. This is 100% SSL/TLS standard compliant, but in
#     practice often causes hanging connections with brain-dead browsers. Use
#     this only for browsers where you know that their SSL implementation
#     works correctly. 
#   Notice: Most problems of broken clients are also related to the HTTP
#   keep-alive facility, so you usually additionally want to disable
#   keep-alive for those clients, too. Use variable "nokeepalive" for this.
#   Similarly, one has to force some clients to use HTTP/1.0 to workaround
#   their broken HTTP/1.1 implementation. Use variables "downgrade-1.0" and
#   "force-response-1.0" for this.
BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

#   Per-Server Logging:
#   The home of a custom SSL log file. Use this when you want a
#   compact non-error SSL logfile on a virtual host basis.
CustomLog "C:/wamp64/bin/apache/Apache2.4.51/logs/ssl_request.log" \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

If somebody could explain me what i did wrong, i'd be grateful !

Thanks for reading

Comment: Please, show your SSL Virtual Host.

Comment: That Is a default ssl virtual host for your wamp homepage, but not for your app. You need to make an ssl virtual host pointing to artogen/web dir with an ssl certificate for your artogen domain name.

Comment: not sure, but try this command "symfony server:ca:install"

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html#enabling-tls